# How should I transform generic observable into specific data model in rxjs 6/Angular 6?

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular6, rxjs5, rxjs6

I am using Angular 6 with RxJs 6 and I have a backend api which will **send the response with generic class object**, which means the response data model is not static, **but I have one more indicator that can tell me what model is passing in**, code example are:

```
interface orderSummary {...}
interface orderDetail {...}
interface IResponse {
    objectType: string;
    objectData: any
}

GetGenericDataModel() {
    return this.httpClient.get<IResponse>(`../api/method`)
        .map?flatmap?pipe?( -->what should I use here?
            (response) => {
                 if (response.objectType === 'orderSummary')
                    return response.objectData.ToOrderSummary --> how to convert to orderSummary
                 else if (response.objectType === 'orderDetail')
                    return response.objectData.ToOrderDetail --> how to convert to orderDetail                           
            }
        );
}
```

On client side when I use http.get to fetch my result and **depend on my response indicator(objectType), I need to convert/transform the response data(objectData) into my interface(either orderSummary or orderDetail)**, How should I work with rxjs to convert/transform my response data into my pre-defined interface in Angular 6?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GetGenericDataModel() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`../api/method`).pipe(
        map(json => {
            if(json.objectType === 'orderSummary') {
                // server needs to make sure objectData.orderSummary matches orderSummary
                return json.objectData.orderSummary
            } else if(json.objectType === 'orderDetail') {
                // server needs to make sure objectData.orderDetail matches orderDetail
                return object.objectData.orderDetail
            } else {
              throw new Error('unsupported...')
            }
        })
    );
}
```